# Laravel insert into Database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have the following problem:
I want to insert into my database, with input fields.
Here is my html:

```
<div class="row">
    <form action="{{ action('test@store') }}" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"> 
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
            <label for="MtrNr">MtrNr:</label>
            <input type="text" name="MtrNr" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3">
            <label for="Vorname">Vorname:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Vorname" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3">
            <label for="Nachname">Nachname:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Nachname" class="form-control" >
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
            <label for="Klassenname">Klassenname:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Klassenname" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
            <button class="btn btn-primary option-button button_rowAllign" type="submit">Schüler hinzufügen</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

My controller:

```
  public function store(Request $request)
{
    $user = new schueler;
    $user->MatNr = Input::get("MtrNr");
    $user->vorname = Input::get("Vorname");
    $user->nachname = Input::get("Nachname");
    $user->klassenname = Input::get("Klassenname");
    $user->save();
}
```

And here my routes:

```
Route::post("{{ action('test@store') }}", "test@store");
```

The thing is, that I already inserted into my database. But when i tried to
reproduce it, it doesn't work.
For local server I use xampp. 
I hope you can help me.

Comment: you miss `$user->save();` in store method in controller.

Comment: thanks, you are right, that was missing
but the problem is still here.
Maybe I have to add something in the model?

Comment: Route::post("{{ action('test@store') }}", "test@store"); is this your route code? and Whats your controller name?

Comment: Yes, but i have changed it to Route::post("/test", "test@store"); like desciped in the comment below. The controller name is test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you only created a new `Schueler` object and gave the data to it. But you didn't save it in the database. You only made local changes.

Use this method to save.

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $user = new schueler;
    $user->MatNr = Input::get("MtrNr");
    $user->vorname = Input::get("Vorname");
    $user->nachname = Input::get("Nachname");
    $user->klassenname = Input::get("Klassenname");
    $user->save();
}
```

Try changing your routes like this

```
Route::post("/test", "test@store"); // change /test to /anything you want
```

Before all make sure you have the database setup and there are all tables in that database like schuelers - For that do `php artisan migrate`

Comment: thanks, I have edited my project but it doesn't solve my problem

Comment: @Rechenmeister then what is the error or problem you get? I have edited my answer

Comment: If I start the application, without php artisan serve, i get no error. The page just reloads and there is no data in database. With php artisan serve, I get the error: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: Table 'datenbank.schuelers' doesn't exist . Which is correct, 'schuelers' doesn't exist, only 'schueler' exist. I don't know where laravel gets 'schuelers'.

Comment: do `php artisan migrate` first @Rechenmeister

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Insert record into the database you miss to add `$user->save()` in your controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $user = new schueler;
    $user->MatNr = Input::get("MtrNr");
    $user->vorname = Input::get("Vorname");
    $user->nachname = Input::get("Nachname");
    $user->klassenname = Input::get("Klassenname");
    $user->save();

}
```

Comment: thanks, I have eddited my project but it doesn't solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

I think something wrong with your route.

```
Route::post("{{ action('test@store') }}", "test@store");
```

Route should be something like below:

```
Route::post("schueler/store", "yourcontrollername@store");
```

//This is sample code, Please update with your one.